# Node.JS: Nodemailer not sending emails even though there's no error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, smtp, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an email using Node.JS and Nodemailer but it doesn't seem to send an email, even though there are no errors. I just don't receive anything.

I'm pretty sure I filled in all the email info correctly, I tried both port 25 and 465. There are no errors when you submit the contact form. I also port forwarded both ports (not sure if necessary).

I recreated my app in the codesandbox below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-moon-d4sm0?file=/index.js

All the data is valid, feel free to play with it. Nodemailer is still new to me, hopefully someone can tell me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! All I had to do was add *smtpTransport* as a parameter in *createTransport* and add the *name* variable.

**Old**

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.sj9.co",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: "test@sj9.co", // generated ethereal user
      pass: "jailbreak", // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });
```

**New**

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    name: "sj9",
    host: "mail.sj9.co",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: "test@sj9.co", // generated ethereal user
      pass: "jailbreak", // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  }));
```